# how to implement background service in xamarin forms ios platform (Using shared project)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I used shared project in Xamarin forms for implementing my application android and ios platform, in that i have implemented background service in android platform but in ios not work out for me, below code implemented in android platform same way have to implement in ios

```
[Application]
class FFA : Application
{
    public static Context AppContext;

    public FFA(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {

    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;

        StartPushService();
    }

    public static void StartPushService()
    {
        AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(FFAService)));
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(FFAService)), 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }

    public static void StopPushService()
    {
        AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(FFAService)));
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(FFAService)), 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        alarm.Cancel(pintent);
    }
```

For service side i have to show local push notification

```
     [Service]
public class FFAService : Service
{
    public static Context AppContext;
    private static readonly int ButtonClickNotificationId = 1000;        
    private int count = 1;
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        DoStuff();
        return StartCommandResult.RedeliverIntent;
    }
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
    {
        Intent restartService = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(FFAService));
        restartService.SetPackage(PackageName);
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.GetService(ApplicationContext, 1, restartService, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(AlarmService);
        alarmService.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 100, restartServicePI);
    }
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            Bundle valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
            valuesForActivity.PutInt("count", count);
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
            resultIntent.PutExtras(valuesForActivity);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
            stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(SecondActivity)));
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);     
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
            var activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
            var sqliteFilename = $"{Common.DatabaseName}.db3";
            var path = Path.Combine(Common.folder, sqliteFilename);
            SQLite.SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
            var val = connection.Query<Table>("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'TicketMessage'", new object[] { });
            if (val.Count >= 1)
            {
                var reslt = connection.Query<Ticket>("SELECT * FROM TicketMessage where Sync = ?", new object[] { 0 });
                //connection.Execute("update TicketMessage set Sync = 1 where Sync = 0");
                count = reslt.Count;
            }
            if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.IsConnectedOrConnecting)
            {                    
                //if (count > 1)
                //{
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .SetContentTitle("Outbox Details")
                        .SetNumber(count)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification)
                        .SetContentText(string.Format("Network connection available. Ourbox have {0} items.", count));
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
                    notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .SetContentTitle("Outbox Details")
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification)
                    .SetContentText(string.Format("No network connection available. Ourbox have {0} items.", count));
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
                notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());
            }
        }, null, 0, 60000);
    }
```

Please help me with this more helpful to me, thanks in advance.

Comment: iOS services don't work like Android. I am afraid you will  not get better answer than to read how iOS services work, sorry

Comment: yeah i find it won't work , but we can achieve it by location manager or audio service, is there any implementation like what i did in android. please help me out this. thanks for the reply!!!

Comment: Can you describe in few words what you want to do in background services instead of me trying to figure out what you have done. Keep in mind if you specify that your service is doing location or audio but you don't do that Apple will reject your app.

Comment: yeah i understood, using service i want to check the networking connectivity to push the local data into server even the app is closed by the user and also we have to check the same when it is goes to back ground.

Comment: You will not be able to do that on iOS exactly as you specify. You have 2 options. 1. Very unreliable. Use Background fetch. Completely unpredictable. iOS will wake your app whenever it thinks it should. You can read more about this feature. 2. Use remote push notifications from your server to wake up your app. You can do it periodically.

Comment: okey, thanks for your valuable suggestion. i will proceed by theway